# How can an extension expand configuration variables in VSCode?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I tried to write an extension for vscode, the extension needs to read `pasteImage.parth` variable from `./vscode/settings.json file`

```
{
  "pasteImage.path": "${workspaceRoot}/assets/images"
}
```

I tried to use `vscode.workspace.getConfiguration()` function to get the variable like this:

```js
let folderPathFromConfig = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('pasteImage')['path'];
```

But it got `${workspaceRoot}/assets/images`, I want `${workspaceRoot}` to expand to the real path of the workspace root, what should I do?

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: This feature isn't currently supported by vscode. [Please  the feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/140056).

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a service for it, you'd have to extend the `AbstractVariableResolverService` similarly to [the debug host](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/a301dc553bede42fe03a9d174a41c8d7816fbaf6/src/vs/workbench/api/common/extHostDebugService.ts#L974-L1023) to do this.

Unfortunately you cannot import these things from within your extension.

---

[The actual implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/f9c6fa3161611aea26df47c33937cb72281d293d/src/vs/workbench/services/configurationResolver/common/variableResolver.ts#L126-L141) is quite straightforward but I do wonder what they thought when they decided against this.

`IProcessEnvironment` is just [a stupid interface](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/9f1aa3c9feecd04a79d22fd6752ba14a83b48f1b/src/vs/workbench/services/configurationResolver/electron-browser/configurationResolverService.ts#L32) for the built-in `process.env` prop.

---

In my own extensions I've dealt with this like [so](https://github.com/leidegre/vscode-clang/blob/master/extension.js#L210-L238).

Answer (score -1):

According to the [vscode extensibility documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_workspace) you can use

```
let workspaceRoot = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0];
```

to get the root `WorkspaceFolder`. You can get the absolute path of a `WorkspaceFolder` by using its `Uri`:

```
let workspaceRootPath = workspaceRoot.uri.path;
```

Then you just replace the `"${workspaceRoot}"` sub string of the `folderPathFromConfig`.
To conclude:

```
let folderPathFromConfig = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('pasteImage')['path'];

if (vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders !== undefined) { // is undefined if no folder is opened
    let workspaceRoot = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0];
    folderPathFromConfig = folderPathFromConfig.replace('${workspaceRoot}', workspaceRoot.uri.path);
}
```

Comment: While a workaround, it does not address the question.